# Mock the input in method inside another method

Tags: python, unit-testing, methods, constructor, mocking

I want to learn how to mock input that has to be typed in, when method is called inside another method 
In this certain example I want to mock user input, that is required to type in when pass_arg() method, executes

**Constructor**

```py
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
    self.add_argument("-u", help="Login. Required argument", default="None")
    self.add_argument("-p", help="Password", default="None")
    self.add_argument("-dir", help="path to directory. Required Argument", default="None")
    self.__args: dict = vars(self.parse_args())
    self.pass_arg()
```

**pass_arg()**

```py
def pass_arg(self):
    arg_p: str = self.__args.get('p')
    if arg_p == "None":
        arg_p = getpass()
    else:
        print("Your password was typed in as argument in CLI. Everyone could see that!")
```

**I tried this:**

```py
@patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['pass'])
def test_no_arguments(self) -> None:
    """Simulates situation when no arguments have been typed in"""
    self.parser = ConfigedParser()
    self.assertEqual(self.parser.get_args(), {'u': 'None', 'p': 'None', 'dir': 'None'})
```

** In this example following code, solved my problem. I just mocked the whole method getpass() **

```
    def test_no_arguments(self) -> None:
    """Simulates situation when no arguments have been typed in CLI"""
    with patch.object(ConfigedParser, 'pass_arg', new=self.moc_get_pass):
        self.parser = ConfigedParser()
        self.assertEqual(self.parser.get_args(), {'u': 'None', 'p': 'None', 'dir': 'None'})

def moc_get_pass(self):
    return
```

Comment: If you are subclassing `ArgumentParser`, I would recommend not calling `parse_args` in its `__init__` method. Let the user of your class class `parse_args` and worry about the resulting values. You are putting too many concerns in a single class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `patch` does is replacing temporarily the value behind the `input` reference by a Mock object that you can freely configure.
Please read how the `side_effect` parameter works : [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock)

In summary you can :

- give it an exception to raise when the patched reference gets called,
- give it a list of values to return, one by one, when the patched reference gets called several times
- give it a function to call instead of the patched reference, and the mock will return the value provided by the function

Here, you configure the Mock to return the string `"pass"` the first time `input` gets called. It does not replace the actual call by a `pass` statement. So the `input()` call is actually made, but it is not the `builtins.input` method that gets called but your mock, which returns `"pass"`.

You did not post the code which includes the `input` call, so I can't provide further assistance, but I recommend you to use `return_value="whatever"` instead of `side_effect` to avoid this kind of error.

Also, take the time to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when posting a question, it helps a lot.